# Refund + cancel subscription Paypal API

Tags: php, paypal

I hired someone to code me a bit of code that cancel a recurring payment in Paypal's API that goes like this:

```
function change_subscription_status( $profile_id, $action ) {

   $api_request = 'USER=' . urlencode( 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' )
    .  '&PWD=' . urlencode( 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' )
    .  '&SIGNATURE=' . urlencode( 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' )
    .  '&VERSION=76.0'
    .  '&METHOD=ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus'
    .  '&PROFILEID=' . urlencode( $profile_id )
    .  '&ACTION=' . urlencode( $action )
    .  '&NOTE=' . urlencode( 'Plan cancelled in application' );


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp' );

[...]
```

Is there a way with the Paypal API to ALSO REFUND an amount X.XX at the SAME time?

Basically, I want to cancel a recurring transaction of, say 10$ monthly and if the client used the software for 15 days, then give a 5$ refund.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would just build a [RefundTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) request the same way you built the ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus request and run them back to back in your script.

Comment: thanks, i'm so new to this that i was lost in paypal's documentation. Although i have a working script, i'd love to understand what's going on under the hood. Do you have any recommendation / tutorials / documentations that you could share in your answer for everybody to see? Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It comes with fully functional samples and ready-made templates to get any API running quickly and easily.

Comment: RefundTransaction requires a transaction ID but it seems subscriptions do not have this - correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: A subscription profile that gets created would not have a transaction ID...it would have a profile ID.  The payments associated with a profile would indeed have a transaction ID, though, and could be refunded via RefundTransaction using that transaction ID.